# How can I replace part of a url?

Tags: php, url, substring, query-string, str-replace

I have the following code:

```
<a href="http://google.com/?id=59&member=michael&day=thursday">
```

I'd like to transform it into:

```
<a href="<?php echo urlencode($alex) ?>&day=thursday">
```

Should I just add the following code in the header, to make it work that way, or what do you suggest me to do?

```
<?php $alex = 'http://google.com/?id=59&member=michael' ?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If `$alex` is set that way, then that's all you have to do to echo the value and it would produce that URL. But I don't think that's what you're asking

Comment: yeah you can add directly no need urlencode here

Comment: I need to encode a long link in a unique word, because I'm creating a script where the base link is so long and repeated tons of times, but I don't want to repeat it completely, and prefere replacing it with a single word. Url encode may be the solution, or?

Comment: you just store the url in variable like string and echo like this <a href="<?php echo $alex ?>&day=thursday">link</a>